# Converting MS SQL to Snowflake SQL, How do I return a count of records using a subquery

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am converting a query from MS SQL to Snowflake SQL and I would like to know how to turn a record count using a subquery (or Snowflake equivalent). In the code below, "NUM_VISITS" returns the number of encounters that occurred for each patient.

If I hardcode a static number in place of "NUM_VISITS", the query works without issue, so I am confident the issue is how I am calling the subquery.  When running the code as presented, I get the following error:

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 15 at position 20 unexpected 'SELECT'. syntax error line 15 at position 32 unexpected '('.

```
SELECT
    
    'HB' as "TXN_SOURCE",
    enc.PAT_ID,
    enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
    enc.contact_date,
    enc.PRIMARY_LOC_ID,
    enc.department_id,
    CASE
        WHEN enc.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1229296 AND txn.PROC_ID = 12255396 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END as "KITCHEN_CLASS",
    "NUM_VISITS" = (SELECT COUNT(enc2.contact_date)
                    FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.PAT_ENC enc2
                    JOIN HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.HSP_TRANSACTIONS txn2
                        ON enc2.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = txn2.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
                    WHERE enc.pat_id = enc2.pat_id
                            enc2.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
                            AND txn2.PROC_ID IN (12255387,12255388,12255395,12255396)
                            AND enc2.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288)
             ,
    txn.PROC_ID
    
FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.PAT_ENC enc
JOIN HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.HSP_TRANSACTIONS txn
    ON enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = txn.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID

WHERE enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
AND txn.PROC_ID IN (12255387,12255388,12255395,12255396)
AND enc.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288;
```

After resolving the syntax issue that was pointed out, I was able to get the code to work by calling the subquery from a JOIN.  Below is the functioning code:

```
SELECT
    
    'HB' as "TXN_SOURCE",
    enc.PAT_ID,
    enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
    enc.contact_date,
    enc.PRIMARY_LOC_ID,
    enc.department_id,
    CASE
        WHEN enc.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1229296 AND txn.PROC_ID = 12255396 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END as "KITCHEN_CLASS",
    cnt.COUNT,
    txn.PROC_ID
    
FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.PAT_ENC enc
JOIN HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.HSP_TRANSACTIONS txn
    ON enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = txn.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   enc2.PAT_ID,
                    COUNT(enc2.contact_date) as "COUNT"
           FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.PAT_ENC enc2
           JOIN HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.HSP_TRANSACTIONS txn2
                ON enc2.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = txn2.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
           WHERE enc2.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
                AND txn2.PROC_ID IN (12255387,12255388,12255395,12255396)
                AND enc2.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288
          GROUP BY enc2.PAT_ID) as cnt ON enc.PAT_ID = cnt.PAT_ID

WHERE enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
AND txn.PROC_ID IN (12255387,12255388,12255395,12255396)
AND enc.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplification of the query in the question:

```sql
SELECT x, 
    1 = (SELECT COUNT(1)
                    FROM (select 1 x)
                    WHERE x = 1
                            x BETWEEN 1 AND 5
                            AND x IN (1)
                            AND x = 1)
             ,
    x 
FROM (select 1 x)
```

You can see that the query as presented will never run, as it's missing at least one `AND`.

To fix the query just add an `AND` before the `BETWEEN` line:

```sql
SELECT x, 1=(select 1),
    1 = (SELECT COUNT(1)
                    FROM (select 1 x)
                    WHERE x = 1
                            AND x BETWEEN 1 AND 5
                            AND x IN (1)
                            AND x = 1)
             ,    x   
FROM (select 1 x);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added the AND and when I ran the code I got a "SQL compilation error: error line 15 at position 4 invalid identifier 'NUM_VISITS'" error. Putting double quotes around "NUM_VISITS" produces the same error.  So I put single quotes around 'NUM_VISITS' and I get this error:  SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting NUMBER(38,0) but got BOOLEAN for column NUM_VISITS.   I tried CAST(COUNT(enc2.contact_date) as INTEGER) as well as wrapping the SELECT statement itself in a CAST statement, both resulted in the same data mismatch error

Comment: I believe I figured out the issue.  Instead of calling the subquery from within the SELECT statement, I used a LEFT JOIN to connect the subquery to the main query and this is returning data. I still need to verify but the initial data is what I would expect to see.  I am new to Stack Overflow, should I post my working code as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it @roneil1967! Best Stack Overflow practice is to upvote and accept answers that others give you when they are useful to you. Also feel free to edit your question and add the fixed final query.